# How can I make the clearInterval stop without creating the loop?

Tags: javascript, math, setinterval, clearinterval

So, I'm very, very new to Javascript, but I'm going through a problem with setInterval and clearInterval.  The problem itself is to generate a number between 0 and 1.  I'm supposed to console.log the answer if it's over .75, and log how many times it takes to get a number that's over .75.  I figured out the Math portion, but my issue is that even though I have the setInterval correct (I think), the clearInterval isn't actually stopping it, but it keeps going, almost like an infinite loop.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
let counter = 0
// var interval = setInterval(randomGame, 1000)
function randomGame(){
    setInterval(function () {
        // console.log(Math.random())
    if (Math.random() > .75){
        clearInterval()
    }else {
        console.log(counter++)
        } 
    }, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save a reference to the interval and then stop it using this reference, constant for example.

```
let counter = 0
function randomGame(){
    const interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (Math.random() > .75){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }else {
        console.log(counter++)
        } 
    }, 1000)
}
randomGame();
```